# A faster way to Convert TXT to CSV, delete TXT & open CSV with a BATCH/EXE (preferably for multiple files)

Tags: csv, batch-file, exe

I´ve copied the content of the following code from various places and tried to trim it down, it works but after I convert it from BAT to EXE it becomes painfully slow. I might add that i´m very new to this so as well as solutions  are any explanations very appreciated.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%F in (*.txt) do (
   set /p .=Processing [%%~F] ... <nu1
   set "firstline="

   (for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in ("%%~nxf") do (
      if not defined firstline (
         set firstline=%%a
         echo !firstline:"=!
      ) else (
         echo %%a
      )
   ))>"%%~nF.csv"

   echo [%%~nF.csv]
)
@echo off
    del *.txt
@echo off
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /O:-D *.csv') do (
    call :open "%%i"
    exit /B 0
)
:open
    start "dummy" "%~1"
exit /B 0
```

Comment: Don't convert bat to exe. The resulting program is always garbage, and people who know what they're doing will be able to look at your source code anyway.

Comment: @SomethingDark Well that would be an option if I only used the program myself, i'm not concerned for the people who know what they are doing, the people who don't though. The reason i why I made this is that the people I work with thought renaming a TXT to CSV was to much of a hassle. Now I'm looking for a way to shuffle it around or take something out in order to make it faster and also be able to handle multiple files

Comment: Why don't you have a script that's nothing but `ren *.txt *.csv`?

Comment: @SomethingDark Mainly cause i'm not i genius :)

Comment: @SomethingDark
This is how it looks now

`ren .txt *.csv`

`@echo off`

`for %%i in (.csv) do start "" /b "%%i"`

Would you do something else with it ? Any suggestions for marking up the content(used cells) of the CSV and cropping it, if i only render one of course?

Comment: I'd swap around the `ren *.txt *.csv` and the `@echo off`, but that otherwise looks right. No idea what marking up or cropping rendered CSV content entails, though.

Comment: @SomethingDark The finished CSV contains 6 columns (from A:F) and I've limited it to 1000 rows but it tends to be less than half. I have another XLSM document that on opening pastes whatever cropped into a nicer, more manageable, trimmed & formatted sheet